# How can I make this rope swing with wind animation holding the tire and being tied to the branch?

Tags: animation, constraints, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

So what i'm trying to do is make a animation where the rope holds the tire at the end and keeps the hold on the three, but the swinging animation will happen when a gust of wind hits the rope/tire. How can i make this ? i Tried to use rigid body, but all the rope falls to the ground and i dont know how to manage the end of the rope holds the tire.

Here is a pic

[image]

EDIT 17/07/2022

I used @moonboots answer, but if you find that your animation kind break after the steps like this : [image] You probably doing the same mistake that i did. So let me be clear, before even u begin with the instructions make sure that when you create the cylinder do Ctrl + A and Apply Rotation & Scale only after this u can continue with the steps. Oh this is important too, your cylinder has to be subdivided so it can move naturally like a rope or will gonna look like is just a straight object leaning to the side
[image]
And that is it, thanks for all the help, especially for @moonboots. If you want a more detail about this solution he made a video explaning how to do this, here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMwDqlRzJ4g

Here is what looks like after all this !

[image]

Comment: Pin the top vertices of the rope.  You may need to do more depending on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

Create a long vertical subdivided plane (object 1), a long vertical cylinder for the rope (object 2), a tire (here a ball, object 3) and a *Force Field* (here a *Wind*):

[image]

Give a *Surface Deform* modifier to the rope with object 1 as *Target*, click on *Bind*. Select the ball, shift select the rope, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices of the tip of the rope and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*. Create a vertex group at the top of object 1, give it a *Physic > Cloth* with the group as pin group. Keyframe the *Strength* of the *Wind* to create the swing:

[image]

The swing will be 2 dimensional (here it won't work well on Y). If you want it to be 3 dimensional, use the same method but with an object 1 that is 3 dimensional (a kind of cage around the rope), and give a *Mesh Deform* modifier to the rope. Play with the *Stifness > Shear* and *Bending* values of object 1.

Comment: +1...but uhm...why isn't the rope fixed to a tree? and why is the tire a sphere in your example? i guess it is because "how many roads must a man ...." ;)

Comment: tires and trees need a completely different solution, mine only work for balls that are hanged to nothing, but please don't tell any one

Comment: balls...of course...normally your comment must be flagged as sexual harassment....you know that, don't you? :D

Comment: I know, plus the rope is not really a rope if you know what I mean

Comment: that's pretty embarassing....and i think you will be banned from SE a minimum of 3 years, 1 month, 4 days, 1 hour and 5 minutes. :D and you deserve that for being so horny....

Comment: I know but I try to get hired in the 3D animation p*rn industry

Comment: and i thought you were already working there....but maybe i confound 3d animation and reality..... :D

Comment: Man, come on, of course, how do you think I got my skills in Soft Body, Fluids and so on

Comment: That’s why you don’t know python….‼️‍♂️

Comment: Hey, i follow u instructions and kind almost worked, idk whats happening but at the final part when i put the cloth physics the animation of the rope and tire goes crazy, i made a video doing the solution that u told here is the link https://youtu.be/07TsfcvRcto  Am i  doing something wrong in the process ?

Comment: You need to subdivide your cylinder, also when you parent your sphere to the vertices of the cylinder, choose some vertices that are around the edge loop, not 3 adjacent vertices. And apply the rotation of your objects. If it still doesn't work please share your file.

Comment: I tried the solution above, and it keeps the same problem. Here is my file that is giving the problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QYuEe2APOQTKFE2TXU1cFfZR4iqlSkTx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Select the cylinder and the sphere and Ctrl A > Apply Rotation & Scale, put the sphere under the cylinder

Comment: IT WORKED ! it was really the Apply Rotation & Scale option that i forgot to do it messing things up. The good things is after all the tries of different form do to i understand the idea i can apply for different things.

Comment: Great, by the way it has inspired me a tuto: https://youtu.be/OMwDqlRzJ4g

Comment: Great video, instructions pretty clear. I already saved too if i forgot something in the process, also i add your video at the solution of the question ! I appreciate